# jquery collapsible theme in php doesn't work

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery code that shows for me collapsibles, when i put the code in html5 it works , But i need that code to came from a php page and being shown in a div in the html5, but it doesn't work ,here is the code that i put in the php + the sql connection and the files of jquerys .....

```
echo"<div data-role='collapsible'>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

  echo " <h4>" .$row['Nom']. "</h4>";
  echo " <p>" .$row['Nom']. "</p>";

}
echo"</div>";
```

but it just shows me in my div the two lines of rows ...

**ADD**:

This is my php file :

```
<?php
$host     = "localhost";
$port     = number;
$socket   = "";
$user     = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname   = "database name";
$value =$_GET['value'];

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="request";


$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  echo'<div id="accordion">';

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo"  <h3>test</h3>
  <div>
    <p>test </p>
  </div>";

}
 echo" </div>";

echo"</div>";
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

and the html5 file is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head> 
   <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

   <script src="log.js" charset="ISO-8859-1"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title> r&eacute;clamation Interne </title>
  <script>

  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });


function showUser(str)
{
var x=document.getElementById('matr');
var str = x.value;
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://IP/File name/test.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>      
</head>
<body>
</div>
  <div class="login">

   <center><h1>Datas  </h1></center>

   <div id="landmark-1" data-landmark-id="1">   
  <div> 

 <center> 
 <form name="data" >

<input type="text"  id="matr" onchange="showUser()" >
</form></center>
</div>
<br>
<center>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Click here to show data</b></div></center>
  </div>

  <div class="login-help">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you've included the necessary javascript and css on your PHP page?

Comment: no the necessary files i put them in html5 page , i've worked with a lot of files with this method , excpet this one

Comment: Can you show us your full code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to initialize the jQuery plugin on an element that does not exist yet. I think it is important to understand what is going wrong, so you can avoid this problem in the future, since this is a very common pattern you're using.

We'll look at your code, starting with this bit...

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
```

...which is executed immediately, as the page loads. Since there is no element with the id `accordion` at that moment, nothing happens (check your console -- probably have an error).

Then, you have the `onchange` code on the input element, which uses non-jQuery ajax to send a request on to your php file. The php file generates some html, wrapped in a div with the id `accordion`, and adds it to the page. That element has never had the accordion-related javascript applied to it, and thus sits there with no functionality.

You've got some of the concepts right, but your timing is wrong. First of all, let's use the jQuery ajax method to simply that code. Also, since you're already paying a performance/load time cost to include jQuery in your project, you should take full advantage of the functionality and use the utility element selector as well:

**The new javascript**

```
(function ($) {
    // used to keep a reference to the ajax request object
    var searchQuery = false;

    var showUser = function (str) {
        if (searchQuery != false) // if there is a pending request, cancel it
            searchQuery.abort();

        var searchTerm = $('#matr').val();
        if (searchTerm .trim().length < 1) {
            $("#txtHint").html('');
            return;
        }

        // clean up the old accordion
        if ($("#accordion").length > 0)
            $("#accordion").accordion('destroy');
        $("#txtHint").html('seaching...');

        searchQuery = $.ajax({
            'url':'http://IP/file_name/test.php?q='+searchTerm,
            'success':function (response) {
                searchQuery = false;
                $('#txtHint').html(response);
                $('#accordion').accordion();
            },
            'error': function () {
                searchQuery = false;
                $('#txtHint').html('Sorry, there was an error');
            }
        });
    };

    // add the change event to the text field, once the page loads
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#matr').change(showUser);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**The HTML**

The only change required to the HTML is that you remove the inline `onClick` event from the input. That said, you are using `center` to center text, which is not a good practice. Use css `text-align:center;` instead -- the less tags, the better (generally speaking).

**The PHP**

Nothing needs to change here, but be certain you are correctly treating the user input that you're getting from `$_GET`. Using `mysqli_*` alone does not protect against SQL injection, if you don't use it correctly. We don't see that code here, so consider this a standard disclaimer: **never trust user input**!

**Documentation**

- `jQuery.ajax` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- jQuery UI Accordion widget - http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: in the new javascript , where is the xmlhttprequest to the php file ?

Comment: it says Uncaught type error : Object#<object>has no method trim

Comment: I've delited those lines , and it works in the browser, since i'm working on a hybrid android app when i tested it in the eclipse it gives me error in that line : xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null ); in the jquery line !? please in idea

Comment: Is it normal , because i don't understand, it works for me in the browser , but now i doesn't work in the browser and it gives me origini null erros !! but i didn't see those error in the first time !

Comment: Yes, that should have been `searchTerm.trim().length < 1`. As for errors in jQuery.... I can't tell you what's going on there. Make sure you're using the newest version, and try clearing the application data/cache for the browser.